# Parity of idempotent elements of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given that the ring R with unity has finite number of idempotents. How do we show that the number of idempotents is even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e$ is an idempotent, so is $1-e$. This pairs the idempotents off, and so you have an even number of them.

I don't know if you want any more ideas for a formal proof. Basically you could just find a maximal set $S$ of idempotents such that if $e\in S$, and $1-e\notin S$. If $X$ is the full set of idempotents, then you can show there is a bijection between $S$ and $X\setminus S$, and since these are finite sets, it implies $X$ is of order $2n$ where $n$ is the size of $S$.

Comment: The map $e\mapsto 1-e$ is its own inverse, you'll notice.

Comment: Wonderful.Bad that I didnt notice it at once.Thank you !

Comment: @Pilot Another trick about idempotents to have in your pocket: $(1-2e)^2=1$!

Comment: To show the bijection between $S$ and $X\setminus S$ it helps to know $e \neq 1-e$. This is easily shown from $e(1-e) = 0$ but $ee=e$ (and $e=0$ doesn't work unless $R=\{0\}$, which is a counter-example, but presumably is supposed to be ignored).

Comment: It is required that R has unity as well,that means R has at least 0 and 1 in it.

Comment: @Pilot Jack's referring to the case of $0=1$ which some people insist on taking seriously　：）